# Loading data from file to Vector structure

Tags: java, file, parsing, vector

I'm trying to parse through fixed-width formatted file extracting x,y values of points from it, and then storing them in `int[]` array inside a Vector. 
Text file looks as follows :

> 0006 0015
>   0125 0047
>   0250 0131

That's the code :

```
    Vector<int[]> vc = new Vector<int[]>();

    try {
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));
        String s;
        int[] vec = new int[2];

        while ((s = file.readLine()) != null) {
            vec[0] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 4).trim());
            vec[1] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(5, 8).trim());
            vc.add(vec);
        }
        file.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    for(int i=0; i<vc.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
            System.out.println(vc.elementAt(i)[j]);
        }
    }
```

But the output shows only last line.

```
250  
131  
250  
131  
250  
131
```

Should I somehow use `Vector.nextElement()` here to get all my data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new int[] on each pass of the loop

```
    while ((s = file.readLine()) != null) {
        int[] vec = new int[2];
        vec[0] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 4).trim());
        vec[1] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(5, 8).trim());
        vc.add(vec);
    }
```

Otherwise you just have multiple references to the same array, which you overwrite on each pass.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically adding the same array three times to the `Vector` while updating its value (that's why the value you have it's the last one in the file).

At the end you will have 3 references in the `Vector` that points to the same variable, you need to instantiate a new one on every iteration, not just at the beginning. This because `vec` is not duped when you add it to the vector, just its reference is passed.